# Why are objects masked after running library(renv) in R?

Tags: r, renv, r-environment

I'm following this steps, like in this workflow [here](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/renv.html):

1. `renv::init()`
2. working as usual and installing new packages
3. `renv::snapshot()`

The problem I'm facing is while running `library(renv)`, many functions are been masked, like load, so I have to re-mask them all over my code in order to make it work again. Like `base::load(...)` Is there a way to avoid this masking?

Here the logs while running `library(renv)`:

```
> 
> Attaching package: ‘renv’
> 
> The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:
> 
>     update
> 
> The following objects are masked from ‘package:utils’:
> 
>     history, upgrade
> 
> The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
> 
>     load, remove
```

Answer (score 1):

`renv` is designed with the expectation that users will normally always use the `renv::` prefix when referring to its functions; e.g.

```
renv::install()
```

For that reason, you normally shouldn't load `renv` via `library()`, and instead should use it via that prefix (unless you want to manage conflicts on the search path).

If you still want to load `renv` as a regular R package, I would recommend using:

```
library(renv, include.only = <...>)
```

to ensure only the functions you want on the search path are placed there.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the `exclude` argument might solve your problem.
like:

```r
library(renv, exclude = c("load", "update"))
```

More secure will be to use methods directly for such conflicts by ::.